# Zero article with the word "sense" in context

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Tell me please why an article was omitted in the following sentence before the word *sense*.

> If you're an ace at picking out fabulous fabrics, accessories, and shoes when you get dressed each morning, you probably have (**a**) discerning fashion **sense**.

It is from [Vocabluary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/discerning).
I am aware that the word *sense* can be used as a mass noun meaning a sane and realistic attitude to situations and problems (this definition is given by the *Oxford Dictionary*), but It seems to me it was used there meaning a keen intuitive awareness of or sensitivity to the presence or importance of something( by the *Oxford Dictionary*). Tell me please If I am wrong, and If am, then why?

Comment: This interests me because it's obvious to me, and explainable, that there's no article with "fashion sense", but then I can't explain grammatically why we speak of *an* awareness. We wouldn't speak of "awarenesses", IMO.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm: I'd quite naturally say *He has good spatial awareness* without an article. It's not easy to think of a context where you might have reason to pluralise ***sense*** or ***awareness*** in such constructions, because in something like *They have good dress sense*, what they've got is essentially the *same* "sense / taste". But I can imagine that the backstory to how a couple of Marvel superheros gained their *different* powers of "superperception" might feasibly explain *how they got their enhanced awarenesses.*

Comment: I didn't mean that the indefinite article is required with "awareness", I was just observing that it's common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that [**fashion sense**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fashion-sense) is kind of a stock phrase usually used without an article.

> [When you can view a season's offerings and unerringly select not only the styles with a fashion future but those adapted to your individual requirements, you display acute fashion sense.](https://books.google.com/books?id=6ZI_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA123&dq=%22fashion%20sense%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_9vKciq3aAhWpq1kKHaZFAWMQ6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=%22fashion%20sense%22&f=false)
>   (Note that this page includes both "fashion sense" and "*a* fashion sense"!)

> [As a market, it functions largely through enactments of fashion sense and sensibility...](https://books.google.com/books?id=S5XNUZlMxsYC&pg=PA42&dq=%22fashion%20sense%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_9vKciq3aAhWpq1kKHaZFAWMQ6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22fashion%20sense%22&f=false)

> [...it makes sense that shoelaces developed as a way to bring color, character, and fashion sense to the shoes](https://books.google.com/books?id=GDoVCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA192&dq=%22fashion%20sense%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiluMuliq3aAhVDq1kKHYM7Afs4ChDoAQg9MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fashion%20sense%22&f=false)

The particular meaning of [*sense*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sense) here is probably closest to "judgement", but "fashion sense" by itself is such an idiom it's hard to define *sense* separately.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is *fashion sense* a set phrase, but the noun *sense* in it has the meaning of the [ability to make good judgments and to behave sensibly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sense) and in that meaning, it is **uncountable**. "You don't use the indefinite article with uncountable nouns" is the grammar rule you should follow.